# flutter: Error: Deserializing to 'BuiltList<UserContentDto>' failed due to: Deserializing

Tags: flutter, openapi, bloc

I have a flutter api which returns an dto array, but the bloc i am using requires a

```
Response<BuiltList<UserContentDto>> response
```

Now, i get the error below:

```
flutter: Error: Deserializing to 'BuiltList<UserContentDto>' failed due to: Deserializing to 'UserContentDto' failed due to: Deserializing to 'UserContentMetaDto' failed
```

It is already failing at this stage, hence i cannot modify the response after i put it into the response:

```
final response =
              await userContentApi.userContentControllerGetAllUserContent(
            page: event.page, // Use event's page and limit values
            limit: event.limit,
            validateStatus: (status) => status! < 500, // Allow status less than 500
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
          );
```

I get the model from openapi, hence i cannot modify the file itself to add a `fromJson` or else.

Here is my bloc:

```
void _onLoadUserContent(
      EventLoadUserContent event, Emitter<UserContentState> emit) async {
    emit(StateUserContentLoading()); // Emit loading state initially

    try {
      final userContentApi = Userapi().getUserContentApi();
      // Retrieve the access token from secure storage
      final String? accessToken =
          await SecureStorageHelper.get(ConstantsHelper.accessToken);

      // Call API to get user content list
      final response =
          await userContentApi.userContentControllerGetAllUserContent(
        page: event.page, // Use event's page and limit values
        limit: event.limit,
        validateStatus: (status) => status! < 500, // Allow status less than 500
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
      );

      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok && response.data != null) {
        // Add a log to inspect the raw response
        debugPrint('Raw API Response: ${response.data.toString()}');

        // Convert BuiltList to List
        List<UserContentDto> userContentList =
            List<UserContentDto>.from(response.data!);

        // Emit loaded state with fetched data
        emit(StateUserContentLoaded(
          userContents: userContentList,
          //  paginationInfo: paginationInfo,
        ));
      } else {
        // Emit error state if response is not OK
        emit(StateUserContentError(message: 'Failed to load user content'));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint(
          'API Call Error: $error'); // Emit error state in case of exception
      emit(StateUserContentError(message: error.toString()));
    }
  }
```